# Adding in Custom Values to jQuery Plugin: Tablesorter 2.0

Tags: jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I'm trying to figure a way out to change a value in my table so it's something else.

For example, if I have a list of these numbers:
1
4
21
6
2
23
0
21
54

I need 0 to be worth the largest amount, so when sorted ascending order, 1 should be in first, and 0 should be in last. Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a custom parser as shown in the [example here](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html). You can use the format function to test for 0, and return `Number.MAX_VALUE`.  I modified the code from the example link to sort the Calculus column using your "0 is highest" rule, below:

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    // set a unique id
    id: 'calculus',
    is: function(s) {
        // return false so this parser is not auto detected
        return false;
    },
    format: function(s) {
        // format your data for normalization
        if ( s === '0' ) { return Number.MAX_VALUE; }
        return s;
    },
    // set type, either numeric or text
    type: 'numeric'
});

$(function() {
    $("table").tablesorter({
        headers: {
            5: {
                sorter:'calculus'
            }
        }
    });
});
```

(Note: the example in the link does not contain a value of 0 in the Calculus column).

Comment: Thanks, I tried this and it also worked:
<div style="display:none">1000000</div>0
..Just adding the large number infront of the 0.